# How to index arrays inside an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing

The Whole thing is I have a 2D Array :

```
int[][] Key = {{1,0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,0},
                        {1,0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,0}};
```

what is needed to split this 2D array in 8*1D array (1 for each block). so i defined 8 new 1D arrays as well as an array list to place all these Arrays in it :

```
   ArrayList<int[]> B_Blocks = new ArrayList<int[]>(); 

   int[] B0 = new int[Key[0].length];
   int[] B1 = new int[Key[0].length];
   int[] B2 = new int[Key[0].length];
   int[] B3 = new int[Key[0].length];
   int[] B4 = new int[Key[0].length];
   int[] B5 = new int[Key[0].length];
   int[] B6 = new int[Key[0].length];
   int[] B7 = new int[Key[0].length];
```

What i need is a some way to index the Arrays in side the array list, for example I want to add the first row values of `Key` to the first Array in the `Arraylist`

P.S The whole point of the arraylist is to gain access easier later for more operations thru forloops for example. Any help Thanks

I tried using the following nested for loop to add values:

```
for (int i =0;i<Key.length;i++) {
       for (int j =0;j<Key[0].length;j++) {
       B_Blocks.get(i)[j] = Key[i][j] ;
        } 
   }
```

It runs but the values arent the same when I output:

```
for (int i =0;i<rightblock.length;i++) {
       for (int j =0;j<rightblockExp[0].length;j++) {
       System.out.print(B_Blocks.get(i)[j]);
        } System.out.print("\n");
   }
```

Comment: The arrayList is, at best, as fast as the 2d array. In fact I think it is implement with arrays internally.

Comment: List implementing classes hold indexes, you can use list.set(index, elem) method to put an element at specified index.

Comment: Could i have a syntax example please ?

Answer (score 1):

If  you want to add an element at a specified index, you can use overloaded [`add(index, elem)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method from list.

```
list.add(0, key[0][0]);
list.add(1, key[0][1]);
```

Comment: How would i use that tech. to add the first row in Key to the first array in the arrayList ?

Comment: Could you please the question again.. I Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements of an ArrayList by using list.get(i). For example:

```
int[] array1 = B_Blocks.get(0);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No..no Why would i put them in a list if i am gonna get them back an place them in another array.

Comment: I'm just saying that's how you could access one of the elements of the list. You can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: So there isnt a way to access the arrays in the arraylist instead of only accessing the arraylist

Comment: Well, since you've named them all before you added them, you can still refer to them by the names you gave them.

Comment: @awolfe91.. I added each array in the arraylist so i could have the ability to access each array thru the arraylist. i.e dont need to call each array at a time to adjust the values, now the question is do i have that ability, if yes what would be the exact syntax. Thank You

Comment: To set a value you could do: B_Blocks.get(0)[index] = value;

Comment: Yes thank you.. Thank, took me a couple of times to explain but thank you

Comment: Could you please the question again.. I Edited

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we should come back to the original requirements:

> what is needed to split this 2D array in 8*1D array (1 for each block)

and

> What i need is a some way to index the Arrays in side the array list

You can work with 2D-arrays like this:

- `Key[0]` will give you the first subarray (='row'), `Key[1]` the second, and so on.
- `Key[0][0]` will give you the first element in the first subarray, `Key[0][1]` the second, and so on. Access to an element, lets say `Key[0][5]`, can also be formulated as

  ```
  int[] firstRow = Key[0];
  doSomethingWith(firstRow[5]);
  ```

The first line lets the reference `firstRow` point to `Key[0]`, i. e. the first subarray. `firstRow` and `Key[0]` point to the same array - you seem to have thought the array gets copied when you stated:

> No..no Why would i put them in a list if i am gonna get them back an place them in another array.

The ArrayList issue:

> P.S The whole point of the arraylist is to gain access easier later for more operations thru forloops for example. Any help Thanks

Nothing is going to get easier if you re-build that structure with ArrayLists - unless you want to add elements to the arrays respectively ArrayLists.